# Content sharing along Image on Linked In not working

Tags: php, html, linkedin-api, meta-tags

I added Open Graph meta tags in head of my Html page for content along with image sharing on Linked In. when i am sharing my web site url it not taking image, it is taking only description. Below are my meta tags

```
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:title" content="{{ $article['headline'] or ''}}"/>
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:image" content="{{ $article['image_url'] }}"/>
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:description" content="{{ $article['headline2'] or ''}}"/>
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:url" content="https://therightdoctors.com/{{$article['category']}}/{{ $article['slug']}}" />
```

please help us.

Comment: Do you really have URL inside `$article['image_url']` and can access it?

Comment: Yes, we have url inside. this is my url

Comment: https://therightdoctors.com/one-more-thing/dr-poonam-malhotra-associate-professor-dept-of-cardiac-anaesthesia-echo-is-the-present-stethoscope-and-echmo-is-the-future-stethoscope

Comment: Tried using only `http`?